# Unfolding menus on DjangoCMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

If I have nested pages, is it possible for, for example, the top level menu items only to show, but when I view a page, for its subpages to appear in the navigation?

So for this structure:

- Page 1
- Page 2

  - Page 2a
  - Page 2b
- Page 3

When I visit page 1 I see:

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

  - Page 3a
  - Page 3b

When I visit page 2 I see:

- Page 1
- Page 2

  - Page 2a
  - Page 2b
- Page 3

When I visit page 3 I see:

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

  - Page 3a
  - Page 3b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and easy. Documentation on the [`show_menu`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.0/advanced/templatetags.html#show-menu) template-tag explains how to do it.

You need to set `extra_active` argument to 1, like this:

```
{% show_menu 0 100 0 1 %}
```

Here are the names of each argument:

```
{% show_menu start_level end_level extra_inactive extra_active %}
```